# Why are some Plutus types defined multiple times in different packages?

Tags: plutus

I would like to know why certain types are defined multiple times in different packages and whether that's suppose to dictate which types to use for on-chain code and which for off-chain code?

Example: **Address** type exists in the following packages:

`Plutus.V1.Ledger.Address`

`Ledger.Address`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is just re-exporting.
Using the imports of the form `Ledger.Address` will mean bumping versions wont require lots of edits of `V1` to `V2` .
This may or may not be desirable. Depends on your context.